# Play - Querydsl not generating Q classes

Tags: scala, playframework, querydsl, typesafe-activator

I am new in using Play framework. I am trying to generate Q classes in play framework project. When I compile program using activator by running command `compile` it did not generate Q classes.

My `build.sbt` content is

```
import codetroopers.QueryDSLPlugin
import play.PlayJava

name := """trainers"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, QueryDSLPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  filters,
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.6.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "4.3.6.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-validator" % "5.2.0.Beta1",
  "javax.el" % "javax.el-api" % "2.2.4",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.3",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
  "com.google.inject.extensions" % "guice-multibindings" % "3.0",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1101-jdbc41",
  "com.mysema.querydsl" % "querydsl-apt" % "3.6.3",
  "com.mysema.querydsl" % "querydsl-jpa" % "3.6.3",
  "com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-collections4" % "4.0",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0",
  "redis.clients" % "jedis" % "2.7.0",
  "com.restfb" % "restfb" % "1.14.0",
  "org.json" % "org.json" % "chargebee-1.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.5.3",
  "net.greghaines" % "jesque" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.velocity" % "velocity" % "1.7",
  "oro" % "oro" % "2.0.8",
  "org.liquibase" % "liquibase-core" % "3.2.2",
  "com.twilio.sdk" % "twilio-java-sdk" % "4.4.1",
  "com.googlecode.libphonenumber" % "libphonenumber" % "7.0.7",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.2",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "rest-api-sdk" % "1.2.5",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "paypal-core" % "1.6.4",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "merchantsdk" % "2.13.117"
)

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=test/conf/application.test.conf"

queryDSLVersion := "3.6.3"
```

My `plugin.sbt:`

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.code-troopers.play" % "play-querydsl" % "0.1.2")
```

Do I need to run any specific command to generate the classes. My Scala version is `2.11.7`. My Activator version is `1.3.6`.